# Place elements one below the other when not enough space

Tags: html, css

I need to have my paragraph side by side with my image. But when space is not enough, I would like my image moved below my paragraph.

How this can be possible ?

Thanks.

```
        <div style="display: table;">
            <div style="display: table-row;">
                <div style="display: table-cell;">
                    <p style="min-width: 200px;">
                        Aaaaa aaaaa aaaa aaaaa aaa aaaaaaa aaaaa aa aaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaa aaaaa aaa aaaaaaa aaaaa aa aaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaa aaaaa aaa aaaaaaa aaaaa aa aaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaa aaaaa aaa aaaaaaa aaaaa aa aaa aaaaaaa aaaa
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div style="display: table-cell;">
                    <img style="width: 250px;" 
        src="http://i.telegraph.co.uk/multimedia/archive/03439/dude6_3439641b.jpg" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/cuga2xp5/

Answer (score 0):

I managed to change your `html code` because it had `inline-css` and etc.

**First way: (With Media Query)**

```
@media all and (max-width: 300px) {
  p, #img {
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
}
```

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jiffiddle/cuga2xp5/12/)**

**Second Way: (Without Media Query)**

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jiffiddle/cuga2xp5/13/)**

Comment: Thanks it works pretty well with Google Chrome but not with Microsoft Edge, any idea?

Comment: I have not IE on my computer and I don't think `media` and `float` are non cross browser. but I going to check on a IE simulator.

Comment: I don't know why but with Edge the text of the paragraph is not horizontally-aligned with the image.

Answer (score 0):

Use flexbox and media query.

- Apply `display: flex` instead of `table-row`
- Use a media query at a breakpoint of 550px (determined by the minimum width of both items side by side) to change the flex direction to column.

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/zer00ne/9kdnr903/1/)

**Snippet**

```css
.ext {
  display: block;
}
.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}
.flexItem {
  display: inline-block;
}
.text {
  min-width: 200px;
  
}
.image {
  width: 250px;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 550px) {
  .flex {
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
  }
  .text {
    max-width: 250px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="ext">
  <div class="flex">
    <div class="flexItem">
      <p class="text">
        Aaaaa aaaaa aaaa aaaaa aaa aaaaaaa aaaaa aa aaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaa aaaaa aaa aaaaaaa aaaaa aa aaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaa aaaaa aaa aaaaaaa aaaaa aa aaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaa aaaaa aaa aaaaaaa aaaaa aa aaa aaaaaaa aaaa
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="flexItem">
      <img class="image" src="http://i.telegraph.co.uk/multimedia/archive/03439/dude6_3439641b.jpg" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks it works pretty well with Google Chrome but not with Microsoft Edge, any idea?

Comment: I believe the quasi-browsers are a little limited with flexbox...I have to dumb it down for IE. Just a minute. Ok, updated.

Comment: I don't know why but with Edge the text of the paragraph is not horizontally-aligned with the image.

Comment: Try changing the following: `.ext {
  display: block;
}

.flexItem {
  display: inline-block;
}`

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Align p and img</title>
<style>
  @media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
 p{
   width: 100%;
 }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 480px) {
  p{
    width: 40%;
    float:left;
  }
  img{
    float:right;
    clear:right;
  }
}
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  
<p>Aaaaa aaaaa aaaa aaaaa aaa aaaaaaa aaaaa aa aaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaa aaaaa aaa aaaaaaa aaaaa aa aaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaa aaaaa aaa aaaaaaa aaaaa aa aaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaa aaaaa aaa aaaaaaa aaaaa aa aaa aaaaaaa aaaa</p>
       
<img style="width: 280px;" src="http://i.telegraph.co.uk/multimedia/archive/03439/dude6_3439641b.jpg" />
  
  
</body>
</html>
```

This is the way, u can get text and image aligned for different devices